# I am asking for a second parameter when I try to create a filtered recordset in in Access using VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am following this code documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/recordset-filter-property-dao

And this is my code:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("mytable", dbOpenDynaset)
rs.Filter = Me.TableControl.Form.Filter

Dim rstFiltered As DAO.Recordset
Set rstFiltered = rs.OpenRecordset
```

But I get the following error: error 3061, few parameters, expected 2.

Why I get an error when I set the rstFiltered recordset? Which second parameter do I need?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have notice the problem is the filter. The filter is this:

```
"([mytable].[myFfield]="a string")"
```

Perhaps this is the problem. Because if I set this filter manually it works:

```
rs.Filter = "myField = a string"
```

But I need to use the filter that is set by the user in the form, that is in the format in which I get the error.

Thanks.

Comment: What is TableControl - a subform container control? Instead of "mytable" and rs.Filter, could use SQL with filter criteria. `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE field='" & Me.controlName & "'", dbOpenDynaset)`

Comment: Exactly how is user setting filter - input/selection in one UNBOUND control? Your manual filter doesn't show apostrophe delimiters for the string input - how can it work?

Comment: I tested code and it works for me. Why do you need to open a second recordset instead of just filtering the first one?

Comment: @June7 Yes, myTable is a subform that shows the data of the table mytable.

Comment: I need to create a second record set to get the filtered records, because according to the documentation it is the way to do.

Comment: Always more than one way, as I show in my earlier comment. I have never used recordset Filter property and I open filtered recordsets all the time.

Comment: Your code worked for me when I used an SQL statement instead of table name: `Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM mytable", dbOpenDynaset)`